# c++ - The Value Changing Before I Save It

Tags: c++

I'm reading a data from a game (SharedMemoryMapped) everything works good,
i got a time of a lap (in milliseconds), getting the seconds = Milliseconds / 1000f,

after that i'm tracking the position of the car until 1.000f which means the end and i need to save some data to the file,
but the lapTimeInSeconds is keep changing in the end of the loop before i get the values i need (Minutes: Seconds: MilliSeconds)

```
while (true) {

//........code........


      // laptime
        float lapTimeInSeconds = (float) ((float)graphic.iCurrentTime / 1000.0f);
        printf("\rLAP: %.3f", lapTimeInSeconds);
        // save
        memcpy(&save_struct.lapTime_seconds, &lapTimeInSeconds, 4);
        memcpy(&save_struct.normalizedCarPosition, &graphic.normalizedCarPosition, 4);
        memcpy(&save_struct.gaz, &physics.gaz, 4);
        memcpy(&save_struct.brake, &physics.brake, 4);
        memcpy(&save_struct.speedKmh, &physics.speedKmh, 4);
        memcpy(&save_struct.steerAngle, &physics.steerAngle, 4);
        memcpy(&save_struct.gear, &physics.gear, 4);
        memcpy(&save_struct.carCoordiantes, &graphic.carCoordiantes, sizeof(save_struct.carCoordiantes));
    
        // write bytes into the file
        fwrite(&save_struct, sizeof(SaveStruct), 1, saveFile);
    
        if (graphic.normalizedCarPosition == 1) {
          fclose(saveFile);
          printf("\nFINAL LAP TIME: %.3f\n", lapTimeInSeconds); // HERE IS THE PROBLEM IT RESET TO 0.000 seconds, the VALUE GOT CHANGED AND SOMETIMES 0.654s 
          uint8_t seconds = (int) lapTimeInSeconds % 60;
          uint8_t minutes = lapTimeInSeconds / 60;
          uint16_t millisecond = (lapTimeInSeconds - ((minutes * 60) + seconds)) * 1000;
          std::string final_file_name = "laps/lap-" + std::to_string(lapCount) + "-" + std::to_string(minutes) + "-" + std::to_string(seconds) + "-" + std::to_string(millisecond) + ".lap";
          rename("laps/lap-not-completed.lap", final_file_name.c_str());
          lapCount++;
          saveFile = fopen("laps/lap-not-completed.lap", "wb");
        }

}
```

The File name becomes 0 minutes, 0 seconds, 659 milliseconds

- How to make lapTimeInSeconds not changing until i save the file ?!

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried ```sleep()``` after ```fwrite()```? maybe fwrite separates from the main process at some point and until it writes data it gets updated by ```memcpy()```, but this is only my assumption which I would still try.

Comment: That's an awful lot of `memcpy()` in allegedly C++ code. Why can't you just copy the `struct`? Could you promote it to a `class`?

Comment: @tadman its a lot of data , and i'm choosing just a few, there are some data i don't need,

Comment: why not just use assignment?

Comment: @PIRIQITI i tried to use write only ones, i was writing every single, 
i just don't get it, why the LapTimeInSeconds changing, its like 0.700s delay

Comment: @NeilButterworth the game gives me the time, and i want to name the file after that time, rename the file, create another file holder, and continue getting the time

Comment: If it's a lot of data, all the more reason to avoid `memcpy()`. These look like small primitives given the size, so `save_struct.gaz = physics.gaz` would be way faster. Even better, just copy the whole thing. Doing it piecemeal can be way slower than just slamming the whole thing over. If necessary, make a copy constructor.

Comment: @tadman so should i copy the whole thing, and pick the things i need to save..
i was trying to not use so much of the memory, but i think i got what u mean,
Thanks for the tip.

Comment: There's a whole bunch of problems here, especially the extensive use of C techniques when far better C++ options exist. For example, if you need to *serialize* this to a file write `operator>>` that does the serialization, and `operator<<` to read it back in from a file. You're doing raw byte dumps of a struct, and this is non-portable and wasteful, those structures are often padded for alignment purposes.

Comment: Normally you should steer towards a form that looks like `save_file << physics` on a binary file stream. Then later to read back in: `load_file >> physics`. If you're using C++, think in terms of C++. Leave all that C stuff behind.

Comment: @tadman Thank you for the quick lesson, sorry for the bad coding, I really did not go to university and i thought C++ is easy xd .. again Thank you.

Comment: Honestly you're probably lucky you didn't take a university C++ course because this is the sort of stuff they teach you anyway. If you want to get a good grip on how to use C++ properly there's books like the *Effective C++* series that covers all sorts of important things. Done right, C++ can be quite elegant. Done badly it can be worse than C. Unfortunately, without more experience it's really hard to know which way you're going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was :
the car position ( 1.000 ) means end of the lap, but the time got reset in (0.996)
so i had to change the condition..

@tadman thanks to you i changed:

```
   // save
        memcpy(&save_struct.lapTime_seconds, &lapTimeInSeconds, 4);
        memcpy(&save_struct.normalizedCarPosition, &graphic.normalizedCarPosition, 4);
        memcpy(&save_struct.gaz, &physics.gaz, 4);
        memcpy(&save_struct.brake, &physics.brake, 4);
        memcpy(&save_struct.speedKmh, &physics.speedKmh, 4);
        memcpy(&save_struct.steerAngle, &physics.steerAngle, 4);
        memcpy(&save_struct.gear, &physics.gear, 4);
        memcpy(&save_struct.carCoordiantes, &graphic.carCoordiantes, sizeof(save_struct.carCoordiantes));
```

To:

```
  save_struct.lapTime_seconds = (float) ((float)graphic.iCurrentTime / 1000.0f);
  save_struct.normalizedCarPosition = graphic.normalizedCarPosition;
  save_struct.gaz = physics.gaz;
  save_struct.brake = physics.brake;
  save_struct.speedKmh = physics.speedKmh;
  save_struct.steerAngle = physics.steerAngle;
  save_struct.gear = physics.gear;
  save_struct.carCoordiantes[0][0] = graphic.carCoordiantes[0][0]; // x
  save_struct.carCoordiantes[0][1] = graphic.carCoordiantes[0][1]; // y
  save_struct.carCoordiantes[0][2] = graphic.carCoordiantes[0][2]; // z
```